# Olive oil instead of peanut oil to air fry potato?

Tags: baking, substitutions, oil, potatoes

I’m allergic to peanut oil, can I use olive oil for baking potatoes in a power air fryer oven elite

Comment: Did the appliance come with a book of recipes?  If there are ones that use olive oil in there, it's probably okay.  (although, you might want to stick with "extra light" olive oil and avoid "extra virgin" because of the differences in smoke points)

Comment: Is your question related to use of olive oil in the air fryer or is it more related to flavour?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Smoke_point_of_cooking_oils) chart, the smoke point of extra-virgin olive oil is 160 C or greater, equal to that of peanut oil, although there seems to be a wide variety in the temperatures reported. In this case you should be able to substitute the oils for cooking purposes. Personally I prefer a higher smoke point oil, such as canola, for frying and baking

Comment: Unfortunately I see a significant issue here. Peanut oil is probably by default refined, which has a smoke point of 232C, much higher than that of extra-virgin olive oil. (Refined olive oil comes closer, for what it's worth.)